# Cannot parse OGC WKT2 file

Tags: coordinate-system, java, geotools, well-known-text

I am trying to parse a OGC WKT 2 string downloaded from https://epsg.io/5822 (shows in the Export - OGC WKT 2 section of the page)

I tried to parse it using geotool's org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2 read method and got "org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown geometry type: GEODCRS" exception.

An attempt to parse it via method parseWKT of class org.geotools.referencing.CRS generated a similar exception "org.geotools.api.referencing.FactoryException: Type "GEODCRS" is unknow in this context".

How do I convert this file to a CoordinateReferenceSystem and use it to transform Positions from WGS84 to the coordinate system represented by the above mentioned WKT2?

I am new to geolocation.

Comment: Can we know in which software you would be using this WKT?

Comment: My own personal project

Comment: The easiest way to convert your data without programming would be to open the data in QGIS, then set the custom coordinate system using WKT which QGIS will parse and validate for you. If the WKT file is on epsg.io, it should most probably support it. Then you just need to save your data to WGS84.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong method. The geometry parser is trying to find geometries from the WKT (for example `POINT (1 1)`).

Try `CRS.parseWKT(txt)` instead.

https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html

**EDIT**

The following may not help with GeoTools but perhaps it gives some information about how the conversion from geocentric WGS84 (EPSG:4328) into geocentric UCS-2000 (EPSG:5558) might happen. This is the operation path that the Proj library would use.

```
projinfo -s epsg:4328 -t epsg:5558

-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Conversion from WGS 84 (geocentric) to WGS 84 + Inverse of UCS-2000 to WGS 84 (2) + Conversion from UCS-2000 (geog3D) to UCS-2000 (geocentric), 1 m, Ukraine - onshore and offshore.

PROJ string:
+proj=helmert +x=-24 +y=121 +z=76

WKT2:2019 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Conversion from WGS 84 (geocentric) to WGS 84 + Inverse of UCS-2000 to WGS 84 (2) + Conversion from UCS-2000 (geog3D) to UCS-2000 (geocentric)",
    SOURCECRS[
        GEODCRS["WGS 84 (geocentric)",
            ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[Cartesian,3],
                AXIS["(X)",geocentricX,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["(Y)",geocentricY,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["(Z)",geocentricZ,
                    ORDER[3],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",4328]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEODCRS["UCS-2000",
            DATUM["Ukraine 2000",
                ELLIPSOID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.3,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[Cartesian,3],
                AXIS["(X)",geocentricX,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["(Y)",geocentricY,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["(Z)",geocentricZ,
                    ORDER[3],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",5558]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Conversion from WGS 84 (geocentric) to WGS 84",
            METHOD["Geographic/geocentric conversions",
                ID["EPSG",9602]]]],
    STEP[
        COORDINATEOPERATION["Inverse of UCS-2000 to WGS 84 (2)",
            SOURCECRS[
                GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
                        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,3],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["ellipsoidal height (h)",up,
                            ORDER[3],
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                    ID["EPSG",4979]]],
            TARGETCRS[
                GEOGCRS["UCS-2000",
                    DATUM["Ukraine 2000",
                        ELLIPSOID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.3,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,3],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["ellipsoidal height (h)",up,
                            ORDER[3],
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                    ID["EPSG",5560]]],
            METHOD["Geocentric translations (geog2D domain)",
                ID["EPSG",9603]],
            PARAMETER["X-axis translation",-24,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8605]],
            PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",121,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8606]],
            PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",76,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8607]],
            OPERATIONACCURACY[1.0],
            ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",5840],
            REMARK["Rounded parameter values taken from UCS-2000 to ITRF2000 (1) (code 7817) assuming that WGS 84 is equivalent to ITRF2000 within the accuracy of the transformation. Replaces UCS-2000 to WGS 84 (1) (tfm code 5590)."]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Conversion from UCS-2000 (geog3D) to UCS-2000 (geocentric)",
            METHOD["Geographic/geocentric conversions",
                ID["EPSG",9602]]]],
    OPERATIONACCURACY[1],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Ukraine - onshore and offshore."],
        BBOX[43.18,22.15,52.38,40.18]]]
```

Comment: Actually I did try it and got "org.geotools.api.referencing.FactoryException: Type "GEODCRS" is unknow in this context".  You probably did not read to the end of my quaestion.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Right, EPSG:5822 is actually a code for the transformation between coordinate systems EPSG:5558 and EPSG:8998. What I did read was that you tried to use org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2 that reads the geometry WKT but I suggested another wrong method for you. But you mention WGS84 in your question and it not EPSG:5558 nor EPSG:8998. Could you clarify what you really want to do?

Comment: I am trying to convert WGS84 coordinates to UCS-2000 coordinates.  I did not realize that a given EPSG code works only for transformation from one  concrete coordinate sustem to another concrete coordinate system.  I thought that a code was fully describing a coordinate system and the same EPSG code could be used for transformation from any coordinate system to the one mentioned in the description of this EPSG code. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

That is not in fact a CRS it is a Transform so you should look to parse it with a `MathTransformParser` or possibly a `CoordinateOperationFactory` but those classes seem not to know about OGC WKT2.

Comment: The contents of that file is all Greek to me.  Do you think that file contains any data I can feed into MathTransformParser directly?  Thank you for mentioning MathTransformParser.  I am just beginning to learn geotools.  I tried to use different EPSG:#### codes for that particular area but it was gving me locations way off.  So I tried to use WKT2 file out of sheer despration.

Comment: I usually just ask for MathTransform between the two CRS I have, so in your case `EPSG:5558` to `EPSG:8998`? either add the actual problem to this question or ask a new one about selecting transforms